# Calculating area with formula gives zero in the attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, fields-attributes, area

I am trying to calculate the area of each patch of a vector on the total area of all my vectors (sum of each area) with the following `"area" / "totalarea"` but then it returns `0`, why?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `Output field type` to `Decimal number (real)`.

You have set the `Output field type` to `integer`. Thus 0,00001713... (as can be seen in the Preview) will be rounded to `0`.

Comment: Hi, it does not work :(

Comment: What are the units of the two fields?

Comment: @Robagb **what** did not work? What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by just adding 10 to the precision.